# How to write a textx grammar rule to detect standard datatypes without modifying them?

Tags: python, dsl, textx

I want to write a textx grammar rule that can consists of either another defined rule or any kind of standard datatype (Int, Float, String etc.).

This is for a simple textx DSL which should have the possibility included to write (and translate in the end) conditions that can consist either of other grammar rules (like predefined functions) or of any kinds of standard predefined datatypes (String/Int/Float/Bool/ID).

So, I actually want to be able to write something like for example

```
condition insert input data 5 equal 10 BEGIN
    ...
END
```

This stands for a normal IF.
The `insert input data 5` is a rule that gets translated later into a normal function call `insertOutputData(5)`. The grammar I use there:

```
Model: commands*=Command;
Command: Function | Branch;
Function: Func_InsertInputData | Func_InsertOutputData;
Func_InsertInputData: 'insert input data' index=INT;
Func_InsertOutputData: 'insert output data' index=INT;
Branch: 'condition' condition=Condition 'BEGIN'
    commands*=Command;
'END'
Condition: Cond_Equal | Cond_And | Cond_False;
Cond_Equal: op1=Operand 'equal' op2=Operand;
Cond_And: op1=Operand 'and' op2=Operand;
Cond_False: op1=Operand 'is false';
Operand: Function | OR_ANY_OTHER_KIND_OF_DATA;
```

In the interpreter, I try to read the code by doing this:

```
def translateCommands(cmds):
    commands = []
    for cmd in cmds:
        commands.append(translateCommand(cmd))
    return commands

def translateCommand(cmd):
    print(cmd)
    print(cmd.__class__)
    if cmd.__class__.__name__ == 'int' or cmd.__class__.__name__ == 'float':
        return str(cmd)
    elif cmd.__class__.__name__ == 'str':
        return '\'' + cmd + '\''
    elif(cmd.__class__.__name__ == 'Branch'):
        s = ''
        if(cmd.condition.__class__.__name__ ==  'Cond_Equal'):
            s = 'if ' + translateCommand(cmd.condition.op1) + '==' + translateCommand(cmd.condition.op2) + ':'
        if(cmd.condition.__class__.__name__ == 'Cond_And'):
            s = 'if ' + translateCommand(cmd.condition.op1) + 'and' + translateCommand(cmd.condition.op2) + ':'
        # ...
        commandsInBlock = translateCommands(cmd.commands)
        for command in commandsInBlock:
            s += '\n    '+command
        return s
```

At `OR ANY OTHER KIND OF DATA`, I tried it with listing the actual datatypes but this does not work.
If I process the model with the DSL code shown above with `Function | FLOAT | INT | BOOL | ID | STRING` as Operand rule, the integers (the 10 after the equal in the example) get converted into floats

```
if insertInputData(5)==10.0:
```

If I process the model with the Operand rule like `Function | INT | FLOAT | BOOL | ID | STRING`, I get an error

```
textx.exceptions.TextXSyntaxError: None:13:43: error: Expected 'BEGIN' at position (13, 43) => 't equal 10*.0 BEGIN  '.
```

The result I would like to see is

```
if insertInputData(5)==10:
```

or

```
if insertInputData(5)==10.0:
```

with

```
condition insert input data 5 equal 10.0 BEGIN
    ...
END
```

but textx seems to always try to convert the value it gets at that position into the suggested type in the Operand rule which is bad in this case.
How do I have to modify my rule, so that it detecs every data type appropriately without modifying anything?

## EDIT 1

Igor Dejanović just described the problem and I followed the approach he gave.

grammar (the relevant part):

```
Command: Function | Branch | MyNumber;
#...
Oparand: Function | MyNumber | BOOL | ID | STRING;
MyNumber: STRICTFLOAT | INT;
STRICTFLOAT: /[+-]?(((\d+\.(\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?)|((\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)))(?<=[\w\.])(?![\w\.])/;
```

code:

```
mm = metamodel_from_str(grammar)
mm.register_obj_processors({'STRICTFLOAT': lambda x: float(x)})

dsl_code = '''
10
10.5
'''
model = mm.model_from_str(dsl_code)
commands = iterateThroughCommands(model.commands)
```

This results in

```
10
<class 'int'>

'10.5'
<class 'str'>
```

so, there is something missing to make the object processor work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each valid integer can be interpreted as `FLOAT` so if you order your rules as `FLOAT | INT |...` you get a `float` type as the `FLOAT` rule will match but if you order rules as `INT | FLOAT|...` for float number the parser will consume the part of the number until `.` and than the parsing won't continue.

This is resolved in the development version of textX (please see [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/textX/textX/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) by introducing `STRICTFLOAT` rule which will never match integer and the built-in `NUMBER` rule is changed to first try to match `STRICTFLOAT` and then `INT`.

The next release will be `2.0.0` and is about to happen in the next few weeks I hope. In the mean time you can either install directly from github or modify your grammar to have something like this:

```
MyNumber: STRICTFLOAT | INT;
STRICTFLOAT: /[+-]?(((\d+\.(\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?)|((\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)))(?<=[\w\.])(?![\w\.])/;   // or the float format you prefer
```

And register [object processor](http://textx.github.io/textX/1.8/metamodel/#creating-your-own-base-type) for your `STRICTFLOAT` type that will convert to Python `float`. After upgrade to textX 2.0.0 you should just replace references to `MyNumber` with `NUMBER` in the grammar.

More information can be found in [the reported issue](https://github.com/textX/textX/issues/97)

**EDIT 1:**

The proposed solution is not working at the moment due to the bug reported [here](https://github.com/textX/textX/issues/182)

**EDIT 2:**

The bug is fixed in the development version. Until the 2.0.0 is released you have to

```sh
pip install https://github.com/textX/textX/archive/master.zip
```

and then you don't need the workaround at all in case you don't want to change the default types.

Comment: Oh, I'm so lucky, thank you for the answer! Makes much sence. I just implemented it like you suggested, but yet Python sees a 10.0 still as string not as float, although I don't get any errors. I do `Operand: MyNumber | Function;` with STRICTFLOAT and MyNumber just as you posted. Do I have to add any imports or something to make the register work?

Comment: Have you registered object processor?

Comment: ```mm = metamodel_from_str(grammar)
mm.register_obj_processors({'STRICTFLOAT': lambda x: float(x)}))```

Comment: yep, exactely like that. So probably the mistake is elsewhere... which is weird, because I don't get any errors that would occur if my grammar does not work or something, I guess. it's just still of class type string...

Comment: Ah, it seems that you hit a bug. I've just opened a new issue here https://github.com/textX/textX/issues/182

Comment: Fixed in the development version. Please, see the edit above how to install.